# Rebuilding a SAN

Tags: windows-server-2008, storage-area-network, hp-modular-smart-array

Because of a mistake in adding disks earlier, I am going to rebuild my SAN.  It is an HP MSA2000, and I am using 2 Windows Server 2008 servers in a cluster.

Please review my plan and let me know if I am on the right track.

I am going to backup fully all data on the SAN, including the Quorum. My plan is to shutdown both of the 08 servers in the cluster. Then remove the new disks from the SAN, followed by deleting the volumes, deleting the Vdisk.  Once the volume and vdisk is deleted, I am going to recreate the Vdisk, and then recreate the volumes to match what I had before. My plan then was to boot up the the servers and hope that the config matches up yet and then restore the data.

As I type that, I realize, I will probably still have to delete the cluster from the 08 server and recreate everything there as well, as the data for the cluster still will not be there and most likely will not be recognized.

I am reading documentation and going over this in my head, however would like any advice from people better than me out there, or whom have done this before.

My plan is to start this Sat night and have it all back up and running Sunday sometime so Monday rolls around all users are ready to work.

Is it just me or is deleting all data on the SAN the most scariest thing and IT person can do?  I swear I will check that backup job several times to make sure I have ALL data on it first!

So please any advice?

Comment: What's scary is your weekend window to get things back up and running.  Do you have an alternative location to run your data from while you restore your production SAN?

Comment: No, that was the other scary part, as it builds the Vdisk and volumes that takes some time, I am concerned about how long it will take.  I wonder if it will be done in time.  I don't have a second SAN.  Maybe need to purchase a 1TB harddrive and install into a server for a temp access until I am completed..   Very good thought, thank you.